# Declaring a positive variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Why I have this behaviour?

```
R /: Greater[R, 0] = True
R > 0
  => True
Simplify[Sqrt[R^2]]
  => Sqrt[R^2]
```

I expect `R` as last result.

Comment: You have to use assumptions: `Simplify[Sqrt[R^2], Assumptions :> R > 0]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: No way to say that `R` is positive once for all?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: thanks for pointing to that question

Comment: It's definitely best to work with `$Assumptions`, but if for some reason you don't want that, and want to avoid `Simplify`, then you could also just define `R = Abs[r]`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to keep a list of assumptions for your system, i.e.

```
assumptions = {R >= 0};
Simplify[Sqrt[R^2], Assumptions -> assumptions]
```

which returns `R` as expected.

Comment: There is no way to attach that information to `R`, so to avoid to recall the `Assumptions` option each time?